# Why do I get the error-message "Undefined subroutine" when calling a function from a module?

Tags: perl, module

I have a module named `Helpers.pm`:

```
use warnings;
use 5.012;

package Helpers;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(my_function);

sub my_function {
    return { one => 1, two => 2 };
}

1;
```

an call it in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Data::Dumper;
use FindBin qw($RealBin);

use lib $RealBin;
use Helpers qw(my_function);

my $ref = my_function();
say Dumper $ref;
```

and I get no error-messages.
But when I put the module in the directory `TestDir` an modify the script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Data::Dumper;
use FindBin qw($RealBin);

use lib $RealBin;
use TestDir::Helpers qw(my_function);

my $ref = my_function();
say Dumper $ref;
```

I get this error-message:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::my_function called at ./perl.pl line 10.
```

Why do I get this error-message?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably forgot to change the package declaration from

```
package Helpers;
```

to:

```
package TestDir::Helpers;
```

Comment: +1: This is very likely the problem. Everything else seems to have been changed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

i think it is because it cannot find your module in lib path, http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html.

```
use lib 'TestDir';
use Helpers qw(my_function);
```

Comment: I suppose in this case the error-message would be something like: `Can't locate ...`.